# Howto use SBMediaController - always throws "Symbol not found"

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-privateapi

I'm trying to get access to SBMediaController, but my app just crashes.  My target is to stop any playing music app in background with `[[[SBMediaController] sharedInstance] stop]`

I use private headers to gain access to privateframeworks, and can use GSLockDevice() to lock the screen, so i think my import should be finde.
I Noticed that there is no SpringBoard.framework in privateframeworks like GraphicServices.framework, could this be the problem?
My error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBMediaController
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/D1CB0D98-1858-406C-AF4B 254BBEA7A73D/iTest.app/iTest
Expected in: flat namespace
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to use UINibDecoder, because UIKit doesn't exist as a private framework either.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot link with SpringBoard. You have to get the class at runtime using objc_getClass() like so:

```
SBMediaController *controller = [objc_getClass("SBMediaController" sharedInstance];
```

By the way, this will only work if your code is running in SpringBoard (aka a 'tweak' or a MobileSubstrate Extension). If your code is running in it's own app (which is your case), you should use the MediaPlayer framework provided by Apple.

Comment: How can I use that framework to find out if music from any app is playing? Didn't find a way to do it with `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` for example...